# Configure multiple virtual host with https+port on apache2

Tags: networking, server, apache2

Here currently running apache2 server with multiple virtual host. two domain are setup `https://run.example.com` and `https://dev.example.com:8005`but `run.example.com` working fine and getting `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` on `https://dev.example.com:8005` domain, Why ?

```
<VirtualHost  *:443>
        ServerName run.example.com

        ProxyPass        /      http://localhost:8001/
        ProxyPassReverse /      http://localhost:8001/
        ProxyPreserveHost On
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard-example.pem
SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/ssl/private/ca-bundle.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard-example.key

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName vm5.dev.example.com
        ServerAlias dev.example.com
        ProxyPass        /      http://localhost:8005/
        ProxyPassReverse /      http://localhost:8005/
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard-example.pem
SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/ssl/private/ca-bundle.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard-example.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but It could be a problem with SSLCertificateFile, you are using one certificate to authenticate two different site. This link could be helpful http://serverfault.com/questions/398655/apache2-reverse-proxy-2-virtual-hosts-ssl

Comment: @Lety domain same and  certificate having wildcard `*.example.com`

Comment: Just a guess. The second block doesn't preserve the host name, so giving the ssl "localhost" instead of the host that would match the wildcard cert.

Comment: @bc2946088 `<VirtualHost *:443 *:8005>` and also change the server name to ` dev.example.com` but still getting same error, Can you please help to resolve or troubleshoot this issues for `https+port`?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and Apache? Also, your configuration is for `dev.example.com:443`, why are you accessing `dev.example.com:8005`?

Comment: @muru `Apache2.4.10`  and I need to configure `https://dev.example.com:8005` ,so here confuse with how to setup virtual host when https with port,

Comment: O.o Is your Apache even configured to listen on port 8005?

Comment: @muru yes `http://dev.example.com:8005` is working well

Comment: @RGG how do you know that's  Apache on 8005 and not whatever application that you're trying to proxy here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52342/discussion-between-rgg-and-muru).

Comment: @muru 
sorry here i'm not understand well, Can you please give me changes to trying

Comment: this http://serverfault.com/questions/219261/declaring-multiple-ports-for-the-same-virtualhosts could help